# tfs re-merge doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

So rolled back my merge successfully in vs 2008 using the tfs powertools tfpt command.

I tried to re-merge and it said there were no changes (but there are).

Which brings another thought to mind. When I checked in my merge it had about 20 files in the check in even though I only changed 2 files. Now, when I did the rollback it only gave me back the 2 files that I changed to check in?

Comment: Have you tried doing a get latest? A screenshot of the branch history would also be useful if possible

Answer (score 0):

Thats the normal TFS behavior. This is how TFS rollback works, TFS rollback is not actually a "rollback" per say, it's a new changeset overwriting the latest version with an old version!

You have branches A (parent) and B (child). You made some changes to B and then did a merge to A. TFS now assumes that all changes from B is present in A and updates it's internal DB with timestamps. When you rolled back the changes in A (parent) it doesnt change the updates made by TFS to its internal DB. TFS just considers that as a new change! So for TFS there are no changes between B and A, because nothing has changed in B since the last merge! Makes sense?

***"When I checked in my merge it had about 20 files in the check in even though I only changed 2 files. Now, when I did the rollback it only gave me back the 2 files that I changed to check in?"***

When you say merge shows 20 files -> if you open the merge changeset you can actually see which all files got edit and which all just got merged. Against each file in the change set there will be an entry saying "merge, edit"/ "merge"/"branch"/"delete" etc. Those tell you what exactly happened with that merge for the particular file.

In your case I am assuming you have "merge" next to those 18 files. Rename is the most common reason that I have seen for this. There are a number of possible reasons. This is not a complete list:

- You performed a namespace operation (delete, undelete, rename) on a parent folder of the files marked "merge"
- You performed a namespace operation (delete, undelete, rename) that had already been performed in the target branch
- You performed a sequence of namespace operations that collapsed into a no-op (eg delete + undelete, or rename a -> b -> a)
- There are unresolved conflicts
- You performing a discard